# frama-c wp const variable and const array

Tags: c, frama-c, alt-ergo

I'm trying to prove some C code with the WP plugin of Frama-C and have problem with example below:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

const uint8_t globalStringArray[] = "demo";
const int STRING_LEN = 5;

/*@ requires \valid(src) && \valid(dest) && len < 32 ; */ 
void copyMemory(uint8_t * src, uint8_t * dest, unsigned int len);

/*@ requires \valid(arrayParam) && len < 32 ; */
uint8_t func(uint8_t * arrayParam, unsigned int len)
{   
    uint8_t arrayBig[512] = { 0 };
    uint8_t * array_ptr = arrayBig;

    copyMemory(array_ptr, arrayParam, len);
    array_ptr = array_ptr + len;

    copyMemory(array_ptr, globalStringArray, STRING_LEN);
    array_ptr = array_ptr + STRING_LEN;


    return array_ptr[0];
}
```

Command:

```
frama-c -wp -wp-rte test.c
```

My frama-c has Version: Sodium-20150201, and alt-ergo is 0.95.2

The result is

```
[kernel] warning: No code nor implicit assigns clause for function copyMemory, generating default assigns from the prototype
[rte] annotating function func
[wp] 4 goals scheduled
[wp] [Qed] Goal typed_func_assert_rte_mem_access : Valid
[wp] [Qed] Goal typed_func_call_Frama_C_bzero_pre : Valid
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_func_call_copyMemory_pre : Valid (275ms) (209)
[wp] [Alt-Ergo] Goal typed_func_call_copyMemory_pre_2 : Unknown (907ms)
```

I have noticed that when I will change

```
const uint8_t globalStringArray[] = "demo";
const int STRING_LEN = 5;
```

to

```
uint8_t globalStringArray[] = "demo";
int STRING_LEN = 5;
```

and

```
  /*@ requires \valid(arrayParam) && len < 32 && \valid(globalStringArray);
    requires STRING_LEN == 5;*/
uint8_t func(uint8_t * arrayParam, unsigned int len)
{
```

the result is

```
[wp] Proved goals:    4 / 4
```

but I don't want to rely on 'requires STRING_LEN == 5;' and prove first example with 'const'. How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Option `-wp-init-const` will instruct WP to consider that `const` globals indeed have keep their initial value throughout program execution (this is not the default, as, although this invokes undefined behavior at some point, some C code seems to consider that `const` is more an advice than a binding rule).

However, in that case, you still won't be able to prove your pre-condition, as it is indeed false: `&globalStringArray[0]` is **not** valid, since it is an array of `const`. If you modify the contract of `copyMemory` to say `\valid_read(dest)`, then everything will be proved with the `-wp-init-const` option.

A few additional notes on your specification, even though they are not directly related to your question:

- The `requires` clause of `copyMemory` does not require `src` and `dest` to point to a valid block of length at least `len`. Presumably you want to write something like `\valid(src+(0 .. length - 1))`
- I guess that you should swap the role of `src` and `dest`, since it is a bit weird to pass a `const` array as the `dest`ination of a copy function.
- Finally, remember that for using WP, every function that is called (such as `copyMemory` here) must come with an `assigns` clause indicating which memory locations might be modified by the callee